# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/resource0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm trying to access the ram in a PCIe fpga device using python and pypcie,
This is my code:

```
from pypcie import Device

#Defining the pci extended BDF connection id of the target device
d=Device("0000:01:00.0")

#Set bar mapping value
bar = d.bar[2]

#Write 
bar.write(0x0000, 0x00000001)
```

Rather simple and similar to the example they have given on their git page.
But when I run the code I encounter the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/Desktop/PCIE_playground/pcie_bar_access.py", line 4, in <module>
    d=Device("0000:01:00.0")
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pypcie/device.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.bar[barnum] = Bar(resfile)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pypcie/bar.py", line 17, in __init__
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/resource0'
```

From this I assume its just a permission issue so I go into the console to try and give everyone permission to RW the file though I assumed I would have permission to do so since I am the only user on the PC, but when I run `chmod 666 resource0` in the corresponding directory
it returns the following error instead:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'resource0': Operation not permitted
```

I tried googling for ways to change the permission but nothing seems to work.

I am working on a Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: You have to run the script with sufficient privileges, may as member of a the owner group or root. You may also add a udev rule to modify the permissions of the device. Make sure you know what you doing fiddling with PCI devices directly can do damage.